# Unable to instantiate metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient in Hive(Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, hive, metastore

I am trying to setup hive 2.3.0 with mysql on Ubuntu 16.04. I have installed Hadoop and it's running fine. I am able to enter hive console, however no commands are being executed instead it gives me an error:

**SemanticException** org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Here's my **hive-site.xml**

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?useSSL=true;</value>
  <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>hiveuser</value>
  <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>hivepassword</value>
  <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I have also created metastore database in mysql using [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-configure-mysql-metastore) link.

[Error Image](https://pastebin.com/vVMNKfBE)

Comment: Can you post the full error stacktrace

Comment: is mysql-connector-java-x.x.xx-bin.jar is there inside $HIVE_HOME/lib ?

Comment: Yes mysql-connector-java is present in $HIVE_HOME/lib

Comment: @Abhi you can view the error image for full stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the solution. The issue that Metastore wasn't instantiate is due to duplicated keys in mysql. Instead of Sourcing the the hive schema from mysql. Use this:`hive --service metastore`

I updated the **hive-site.xml** too:

```
<configuration>
 <property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/metastore?useSSL=false</value>
  <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
  <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
  <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
  <value>Username</value>
  <description>user name for connecting to mysql server</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
  <value>Password</value>
  <description>password for connecting to mysql server</description>
</property>
<property>
 <name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>datanucleus.fixedDatastore</name>
 <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
 <value>True</value>
</property>
```

Also to view the complete stack trace use **schematool**:
`schematool -initSchema -dbType mysql --verbose`